# change pycharm default primary project

Tags: pycharm

I work on two projects A and B in two windows of pycharm v2016
How can I change the primary project from A to B?
Every time that I run pycharm, project A opens by default. I want project B be opened.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open pycharm, the project that gets opened puss the last project that was open during the last session.

Thus, if you want project B to be opened automatically, project B is the last project (window) that you should close.